# I have a status bar but how do I make it work?

Tags: python, pygtk, connect, statusbar

This code shows me a status bar. However when I click a button it does not say that I have done so in the status bar.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

import subprocess

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_size_request(400, 500)
        window.set_title("GTK Menu")
        window.connect("delete_event",
                       lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        window.add(vbox)
        vbox.show()

        button = gtk.Button("Write")
        button.connect("clicked", self.clicked_Write)
        vbox.pack_end(button, True, True, 2)
        button.show()

        button2 = gtk.Button("Draw")
        button2.connect("clicked", self.clicked_Scrible)
        vbox.pack_end(button2, True, True, 2)
        button2.show()

        button3 = gtk.Button("Final Test")
        button3.connect("clicked", self.clicked_Final)
        vbox.pack_end(button3, True, True, 2)
        button3.show()

        button4 = gtk.Button("Helloworld")
        button4.connect("clicked", self.clicked_Hello)
        vbox.pack_end(button4, True, True, 2)
        button4.show()

        button5 = gtk.Button("Facebook")
        button5.connect("clicked", self.clicked_Facebook)
        vbox.pack_end(button5, True, True, 2)
        button5.show()

        # Add status bar to vbox
        self.statusbar = gtk.Statusbar()
        vbox.pack_start(self.statusbar, False, False, 0)



        window.show_all()


    def clicked_Write(self, widget):
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "Helloworld.py"])

    def clicked_Scrible(self, widget):
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "scrible.py"])

    def clicked_Final(self, widget):
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "Final.py"])

    def clicked_Hello(self, widget):
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "Helloword.py"])

    def clicked_Facebook(self, widget):
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "facebookfinal.py"])


    def main(self):
        gtk.main()
        return 0

Example().main()
```

Comment: Make sure to format your code examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly update the statusbar by pushing a message to it. The documentation has [a brief example showing how the statusbar works](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-Statusbars.html#statusbarfig):

Try this part, and let me know if the message shows:

```
def clickedWrite(self, widget):
    # push a new message to the statusbar, using context_id 0
    self.statusbar.push(0, "called Write")
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "Helloworld.py"])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
def clickedWrite(self, widget):
    # push a new message to the statusbar, using context_id 0
    self.statusbar.push(0, "called Write")
    while gtk.events_pending():
       gtk.main_iteration_do(False)
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "Helloworld.py"])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448217/pygtks-strange-problem-about-set-buttons-sensitive-property/5448610#5448610